# Getting my iOS app download count without iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

With iTunesConnect closing for the holiday, is there a way to get those download and sales data? I can still access to my ads count by visiting iAd. I am wondering if there's something similar for the download count. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you have some analytical service installed like flurry, you could through their service I guess.

Comment: just found the URL. https://reportingitc.apple.com/subdashboard.faces. This can still get me the numbers.